# Uploading a large size file using a SOAP request in C#.net and passing this to a web service API in VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, soap

We are uploading a large size file using a SOAP request developed in C#.net and passing this to a web service API developed in VB.net.

In the existing logic we have implemented Base64 encoding algorithm and the respective code snippet is shown below.

```
Byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(FileName);
Base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

But in this scenario, we are able to upload a file until 70 MB in IIS 7.0 server. We are encountered with an issue with the file size beyond that.

Now we would require solution to know about how to upload a large size (say for example, more than 500 GB) file by sending as SOAP attachments to a SOAP request API. We would also like to know the possible way to send it via mime-soap attachments.

Sample XML data:-

http://www.dummy.com' xmlns:xsd='http://www.dummy.com' xmlns:soap='http://dummy.com/soap/envelope/'>

`Referred links1`https://www.theserverside.com/news/1363957/Sending-Attachments-with-SOAP
`Referred links2`https://community.boomi.com/s/article/mime-soap-attachments

Comment: The upload is probably being done using FTP and a lot of server have max limits fo under 100MB.  You need to talk to the server MIS people.  If the folder was shared, you could copy directly to the folder with proper credentials.

Comment: We actually need to send from C# application to web service developed in Vb.Net. Hence we are not using FTP here.

Comment: We are uploading a large file size using c# application(.Net Framework 4.5) to web service(written in vb.net which receive SOAP Request 1.1).
Problem Description:
While doing the above mentioned action, we are converting the file content into Base 64 string and sending it as part of XML data. Since the string limit is not allowing to hold such a big file's base64 string, we are unable to upload the file.

In c# we are converting the file to base64 and sending to WebService Using HTTPClient. On WebService, we converting base64String back to file and store it.

Comment: Where is the service reading the file (or storing)?  If it is a file then does it matter how it is transferred?  You issue is the limits in the server and need to work with the server maintenance people.  I'm just suggesting if may be easier to just load the file to the server.  Or have the service read from a Network Location that you can copy the file.

Comment: @jdweng FYI, we have increased the maxRequestLength="2147483647" and <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2147483648" /> in website. 

  **Problem:** In C# application, when we concat large Base64String (ie., 100MB string), to create SOAP XML request, the String.Concat throw System.OutOfMemory Exception. So we dicided to not to send file as Base64String in HttpRequest body. 

  **Help Required:** We are dicided to switch to send file as SOAP Attachment(MIME). But we dont know how to send SOAP Attachment using c# HTTPClient and how to received SOAP Attachment in ASP.NET(VB) WebService.

Comment: See following : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6339d63d-88ac-45bd-8387-fe0bf9d8ded4/upload-attachment-using-httpclient-postasync-fails-quotthe-handshake-failed-due-to-an-unexpected?forum=tfsgeneral